# I cannot parse a file because of implicit definitions in ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have a problem when I try to parse a file on ANTLR4. I'm using the ANTLR4 plugin on IntelliJ and the program always throws me these warnings which makes me unable to parse any file or text using the plugin. If I use the console I also get the same errors. This is what I'm getting:

```
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:6:9: implicit definition of token ENTERO in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:6:23: implicit definition of token FLOAT in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:7:16: implicit definition of token ID in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:9:14: implicit definition of token OPERADOR in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:11:27: implicit definition of token IGUAL in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:15:8: implicit definition of token ABREPARENTESIS in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:15:31: implicit definition of token COMA in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:15:45: implicit definition of token CIERRAPARENTESIS in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:17:23: implicit definition of token CIERRASENTENCIA in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:29:20: implicit definition of token FUNC in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:29:105: implicit definition of token ENDFUNC in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:32:38: implicit definition of token LOGICO in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:37:5: implicit definition of token IF in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:37:65: implicit definition of token ELSE in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:37:84: implicit definition of token ENDIF in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:38:7: implicit definition of token BEGIN in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:38:25: implicit definition of token END in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:39:8: implicit definition of token WHILE in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:39:70: implicit definition of token ENDWHILE in parser
warning(125): ParserPF.g4:40:9: implicit definition of token RETURN in parser
```

I have tried everything but it still doesn't work and I'm starting to lose my mind with this. Could it be a bug with ANTLR? My grammar (lexer and parser) looks like this:

My lexer:

```
lexer grammar LexerPF;
//Palabras reservadas
BEGIN : 'Begin';
END: 'End';
IF : 'If';
THEN : 'Then';
ELSE : 'Else';
ENDIF : 'EndIf';
WHILE : 'While';
ENDWHILE : 'EndWhile';
FUNC : 'Func';
ENDFUNC : 'EndFunc';
RETURN : 'Return';
PRINT : 'Print';

//Operadores
IGUAL : '=';
OPERADOR : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '%' | '**';
LOGICO : '<' | '>';
SQRT : 'sqrt';
ABREPARENTESIS : '(';
CIERRAPARENTESIS : ')';
COMA : ',';
CIERRASENTENCIA : ';';

//Identificador
ID : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;

//Números
ENTERO : [1-9][0-9]* | [0-9];
FLOAT : [1-9][0-9]* '.' [0-9]+;


NEWLINE: ('\r\n'|'\n'|'\r')+ -> skip;
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;
```

My parser:

```
parser grammar ParserPF;

numero : ENTERO #int | FLOAT #float;
identificador : ID;
numID : numero #num | identificador #id;
expr :  numID OPERADOR numID
        | numID (OPERADOR numID)*;
asignacion : identificador IGUAL expr #assignExpr
            | identificador IGUAL numID #assignNumID
            | identificador IGUAL llamadaAfuncion #assignCallFunction;

array : ABREPARENTESIS numID ( COMA numID )* CIERRAPARENTESIS;

sentencia:  asignacion CIERRASENTENCIA  #assignSentence
            | llamadaAfuncion CIERRASENTENCIA  #callFunctionSentence
            | if_ CIERRASENTENCIA  #ifSentence
            | while_ CIERRASENTENCIA  #whileSentence
            | return_ CIERRASENTENCIA  #returnSentence
            | begin CIERRASENTENCIA  #beginSentence
            | declaracionfuncion CIERRASENTENCIA #declareSentence;

programa: sentencia*; //Regla principal


llamadaAfuncion: identificador ABREPARENTESIS numID* ( COMA numID )* CIERRAPARENTESIS;
declaracionfuncion: FUNC identificador ABREPARENTESIS numID* ( COMA numID )* CIERRAPARENTESIS sentencia* ENDFUNC;


condicion   : (ABREPARENTESIS* numero LOGICO numero CIERRAPARENTESIS*) #numAnum
            | (ABREPARENTESIS* identificador LOGICO numero CIERRAPARENTESIS*) #idAnum
            | (ABREPARENTESIS* identificador LOGICO identificador CIERRAPARENTESIS*) #idAid
            | ABREPARENTESIS* numero LOGICO identificador CIERRAPARENTESIS* #numAid
            | llamadaAfuncion #boolean;
if_: IF (ABREPARENTESIS condicion CIERRAPARENTESIS)  sentencia* (ELSE  sentencia*)? ENDIF;
begin: BEGIN  sentencia* END;
while_: WHILE (ABREPARENTESIS condicion CIERRAPARENTESIS)  sentencia* ENDWHILE;
return_: RETURN (expr|identificador|llamadaAfuncion|condicion);
```

Comment: How is your parser supposed to know which lexer to use? You are missing something like `options {   tokenVocab = ParserPF; }`.

Comment: As a matter of terminology: warnings are not errors.

Comment: @Clashsoft you just made my day, it was `options {   tokenVocab = LexerPF; }` and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: @0xracer Good to see you solved your problem.  Now you can draft, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question explaining the solution, for posterity.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. But, just in case others had specified the tokenVocab option and still see the "implicit definition of token" warning, it can be caused by missing lexer symbol rules.